# Compiling three C++ files. Linking error

Tags: c++, macos, compilation

I'm in OSX Yosemite, and I have three C++ files I'm trying to compile.

BinModel01.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double RiskNeutProb(double U, double D, double R)
{
    return (R-D)/(U-D);
}

double S(double S0, double U, double D, int n, int i)
{
    return S0 * pow(1+U, i) * pow(1+D, n-i);
}

int GetInputData(double& S0, double& U, double& D, double& R)

{
    // Entering data
    cout << "Enter S0: "; cin >> S0;
    cout << "Enter U: "; cin >> U;
    cout << "Enter D: "; cin >> D;
    cout << "Enter R: "; cin >> R;
    cout << endl;

// making sure that 0 < S0, -1 < D < U, -1 < R}
if (S0 <= 0.0 || U <= -1.0 || D <= -1.0 || U <= D || R <= -1.0)
{
    cout << "Illegal data ranges" << endl;
    cout << "Terminating program" << endl;
    return 1;
}

// Checking for arbitrage
if (R >= U || R <= D)
{
    cout << "Arbitrage esists" << endl;
    cout << "Terminating program" << endl;
    return 1;
}

cout << "Input data checked" << endl;
cout << "there is no arbitrage" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Main04.cpp

```
#include "BinModel01.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double S0, U, D, R;

    if (GetInputData (S0, U, D, R)==1) return 1;

    // Compute risk-newutral probability
    cout << "q = " << RiskNeutProb(U, D, R) << endl;

    // Compute stock price at node n = 3, i =2
    int n = 3; int i = 2;

    cout << "n = " << n << endl;
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    cout << "S(n, i) = " << S(S0, U, D, n, i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and BinModel.h

```
#ifndef BinModel01_h
#define BinModel01_h

// Computing risk-neutral probability
double RiskNeutProb(double U, double D, double R);

// computing the stock price at node n, i
double S(double S0, double U, double D, int n, int i);

// Inputting, displaying and checking model data
int GetInputData(double& S0, double& U, double& D, double& R);

#endif
```

When I go to terminal I start the compiler with G++, I get an error:

```
g++ BinModel01.cpp

    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So then I tried to compile a different file

```
g++ Main04.cpp

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "GetInputData(double&, double&, double&, double&)", referenced from:
      _main in Main04-af9499.o
  "RiskNeutProb(double, double, double)", referenced from:
      _main in Main04-af9499.o
  "S(double, double, double, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in Main04-af9499.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Specify all your .cpp files on the same compile command. Either that, or compile with `-c` to generate object files and link separately.

Comment: Why include the source for a linking question?

Comment: Because this is the first time I've ever linked/compiled anything in C++ and I wanted to be thorough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building the files as separate programs, not as separate source files that needs to be linked. When you don't specify any special flags, `gcc` compiles *and* links the program as a single entity without any external files.

There are basically two solutions: Build both files together:

```
$ g++ BinModel01.cpp Main04.cpp
```

The above command will compiler both source files and then link them together into the executable `a.out` file.

Or you can compile the source files separately into object files, and then link the object files together:

```
$ g++ -c BinModel01.cpp
$ g++ -c Main04.cpp
$ g++ BinModel01.o Main04.o
```

The option `-c` tells GCC to only compile the source file, and generate an object file that can later be used for linking.

The first method is okay if you only have a few source files and don't care about compiling files that haven't been updated. The second method is often used when you have more files and you only want to compile the ones that have actually changed. It is also the method used when using tools such as Make.